# Text inside WPF Shapes

Tags: wpf, shapes

I found [this](https://wpfshapes.codeplex.com/) and I am using the `SpeechBubble`. Is a simple way to add simple text inside this shape?
I tried to find `Text` or `Content`.
I also tried to put `Label` or `TextBlock` inside but I get the message :

> The type 'SpeechBubble' does not support direct content.

Answer (score 0):

When an element does *not support direct content*, you can simply put it into a `...Panel` or `Grid` control... then you'll be able to add other content *over the top of it*. Take this simple example:

```
<Grid>
    <SpeechBubble ... />
    <TextBlock Text="I'm on top of the Speech Bubble!" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Centre" VerticalAlignment="Centre" />
</Grid>
```

However, I wouldn't be surprised if there is a property in the `SpeechBubble` control that enables you to add text to it directly... see if there is a `Text` or `Content` property on it and use that if it does.

Comment: Currently the text i out of my SpeechBubble and also my SpeechBubble is should move accross progress bar

Comment: This website is *not* here to teach you new languages. It's here to help with specific problems. You asked a specific question and I answered that question.